# How to login to Azure AD with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I'm using activedirectory package from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory)
[Example from activedirectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWAkq.png)
Where do I get the URL? Tried it with my default Azure Active Directory:
[Azure AD Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oT02J.png)
The error is:

---

**EDIT**

I can't use the npm package I mentioned before. To be able to authenticate users to my app I need a client key and secret.

I still can't figure out how to let users login with user and password using Azure Active Directory with NodeJS. I want to be able to send a request with user and password and get back information for that user if it exists.

The examples and quickstart guides show SSO scenarios with session or cookies. I can't find how to do what I want.

Comment: Can you please provide more details, step you performed and the error log for us to help?

Comment: Can you explain the scenario that you are trying to achieve? The npm package that you gave is for Active Directory and not for Azure Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [adal for node.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs) to login to Azure AD with NodeJS. The website sample can be found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/blob/master/sample/website-sample.js). Just change the sampleParameters with your own values.

```
  sampleParameters = {
    tenant : 'XX.onmicrosoft.com',
    authorityHostUrl : 'https://login.windows.net',
    clientId : '702b90f1-f6bXXX3-b71f-13edfcaa0c25',
    clientSecret:"_XR-bt7H_XXXYqBrlAsPEk7f8wmszj5"
  };
```

**tenant**

[image]

**clientId**

[image]

**clientSecret**

[image]

Test result on my side.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! You rock!